# Store output from df to PHP array

Tags: php, html, arrays, raspberry-pi

I building an HTML dashboard for my Raspberry Pi and am pretty new to PHP. I'm trying to store the output from df to an array (I think) to later echo on the HTML page.

The df command is I'm passing through exec() is:

```
df -Tl -BMB -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs | grep -v Filesystem | column -t
```

The output I receive (from the shell) is:

```
/dev/root       ext4  31331MB  1214MB  28816MB  5%   /
/dev/mmcblk0p1  vfat  63MB     22MB    42MB     35%  /boot
```

Is there a way to store each value (from each line) into an array so i can echo it in the HTML page? Using something like the below?

```
<tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>Disk space (MB)</td>
    <td><pre><?php echo $disks[0]; ?></pre></td>
    <td><pre><?php echo $disks[1]; ?></pre></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you look at the `exec()` docs? http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: @AbraCadaver, yes, I'm using exec()      $disks = exec('df -Tl -BMB -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs | grep -v Filesystem | column -t');

Comment: I know you're using it.  I asked if you read the docs? Especially where it states _If the **output** argument is present, then the specified array will be filled with every line of output from the command._

Comment: Sorry, did not see that. But it seems that it's storing the output of each character as an array entry (e.g., <?php echo $disks[0]; ?><?php echo $disks[1]; ?><?php echo $disks[2]; ?><?php echo $disks[2]; ?> outputs to the text "/dev"). Is there a way to store each column entry as an array entry?